# WPF ColorAnimation inside Window.Resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, effects, coloranimation

I have a TextBlock that I would like to give it a color animation effect; I have done something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimateTarget" RepeatBehavior="Forever">

        <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="False" Duration="0:0:5" From="Red" To="black" Storyboard.TargetName="txtBarcode" AccelerationRatio="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">

        </ColorAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

I start the animation from code behind:

```
((Storyboard)this.Resources["AnimateTarget"]).Begin();
```

but when i start the animation its give me the following error:

'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.

I would priciest if someone helps me on this,

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `TextBlock` any `Background` and it will work.

```
<TextBlock Name="txtBarcode"
           Background="Transparent"
```

Probably `Background` is `Null` and so there is no `DependencyObject` to animate.